# How can I get a list of arguments from an ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to get the different arguments from an ArgumentParser object? 
Let's assume I have the following ArgumentParser:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, allow_abbrev=True)
parser.add_argument("--help", action="store_true", help="Provides help on usage.")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--user", help="A User, could be their tag or User ID.")
parser.add_argument("-hi", "--upper", type=int, default=100, help="The highest stat to include, this is inclusive. Should be an integer type.")
parser.add_argument("-lo", "--lower", type=int, default=0, help="The lowest stat to include, this is inclusive. Should be an integer type.")

# ...
```

Ideally I would want a list like this:

```
[
    {"name": "help", "help":"Provides help on usage."},
    {"name": "user", "help":"A User, could be their tag or User ID."},
    {"name": "upper", "help":"The highest stat to include, this is inclusive. Should be an integer type."},
    {"name": "lower", "help":"The lowest stat to include, this is inclusive. Should be an integer type."}

    # ...
]

# or even better
[
    Argument,
    Argument,
    Argument,
    Argument

    # where you can use Argument.help or Argument.name
]
```

The best approach I can see is using `parser.format_help()` in order to get the usage output, then 
splitting and parsing that into the right format, but there has got to be a different approach.

What can I do to get an ArgumentParser's arguments?

Comment: have you tried to look at ```parser.__dict__```?

Comment: I have not yet tried that, no. `parser.__dict__["_actions"]` seems to have a list of arguments where I could get info using `parser.__dict__["_actions"][idx].dest` or other, that would be exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parser._actions` is a list of instances of subclasses of `Action`. Each action has an `option_strings` attribute, which is a list of the strings that match. You'll need to extract the longest option string, as you don't want separate results for each short option (eg. both -u and --user)

```
actions = []
for action in parser._actions:
    longest = ''
    for option in action.option_strings:
        option = option.lstrip('-')
        if len(option) > len(longest):
            longest = option
    actions.append({'name': longest, 'help': action.help})
```

The actions list is then a list of dicts with name and help keys.

Comment: Each `action` in the `parser._actions` list has a `dest` and `help` attribute.  The `dest` isn't the longest option_string, but rather the first 'long', See the code in `argparse._Actions_container._get_optional_kwargs`.  So your code is a somewhat erroneous duplicate :) .